# Google channel API for android and iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-app-engine, channel-api

I've been testing my app on mobiles and want to include channel API so I could get live notifications( as it is included in desktop version ) but I noticed that I don't get anything from the channel on my phone.

I've been looking for the solution but the only thing I found is C2DM - https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

but it's no longer under development.

I've been also testing google channel API with Ripple Mission Control on Chrome, and when it's turned on I only get note that I connected to channel but when I make some changes in my app I don't get anything.
When I turn it off then everything works..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the channel API is not supported for Java client (or iOS):
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4189

Yes, you should use each platform's native push notification technology - the successor to C2DM is Google Cloud Messaging:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

On iOS I believe it is APNS:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service